# How to fix black screen while rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render an animation, but I only get black png's. I've looked on the internet for solutions but none of them worked. I saw lots of people that had the same problem, fixed it with connecting the nodes in the compositing section, but that didn't work for me.

My file: [image]

Comment: There could be a million different things happening, no one can answer this if you don't show us some screenshots of your setup, or share your file on blend-exchange.com

Comment: Your World *Strength* is set to $0$ https://i.imgur.com/BW84Eym.png Which means you have zero lights. You can change the color, up the strength, add light objects, use an HDRI...